# Limit points of a product space

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I'm new to topology and am trying some exercises in Gaal's Point Set Topology (p 63). How do I show that the set of limit points of the product space $(A × B)' = (A' × \overline B\ ) ∪ ( \overline A\ × B')$? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: If $A=B=\{\frac1n\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \subseteq \Bbb R$, then $(0,0) \in (A\times B)'$ but it'a not in the union. So a false statement.

Comment: I see - thank you. Perhaps it should have read $(A × B)' = (A' × \overline B\ ) ∪ (\overline A\ × B')$?  I don't have a deep enough understanding of the material yet and will spend more time on it before attempting exercises.

Comment: the one with closures is true yes.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a hint as to how to show that the above one with closure is true?  I suspect it has to do with the fact that $\overline A\ = A ∪ A'$ and the definition of the product topology, but I am lost...

Comment: someone else please make it a dupe to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/990755/4280) ? I cannot.